# Calculating in Python by request from sql

Tags: python, sql

I have a database with a large number of rows (each row represents the amount of sales for a given month). How can I calculate the total sum from the database and print it in a Python programm ?

For the program below I get an error stating that TotalSum is not defined.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT SUM(reel_bom_hdr_m1) AS TotalSum FROM Main''')

print TotalSum
```

Comment: Have you defined `TotalSum` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign output of your query to variable, as shown bellow. it will solve your problem.

```
TotalSum= cur.execute('''SELECT SUM(reel_bom_hdr_m1) FROM Main''')
```

Comment: I think you mean `fetchall`